# Barracuda 7200.12 making a very loud sound (squeak). Drive is not showing

Tags: hard-drive, hard-drive-failure

I have a Barracuda 7200.12 1TB, the drive is not being detected by any OS, before i spin the platters myself that hard drive would make a click sound as if the heads are trying to move but the platters are not spinning and then a low pitch beeping sound.

After i opened the hard drive I forced it to spin in a slow motion then it took off. from there, the strange loud noise came up.

I just think it's the platter being misaligned which is a big problem :) attached is a video for that sound.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2K_neijG1rE

Now after tuning screws as David suggested. I have been able to see the disk in my disk list twice. below is dmesg log.

```
[  986.211268] sd 1:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg1 type 0
[  986.211651] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] 1953525168 512-byte logical blocks: (1.00 TB/932 GiB)
[  986.211947] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] Write Protect is off
[  986.211952] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] Mode Sense: 28 00 00 00
[  986.212325] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] No Caching mode page found
[  986.212335] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
[ 1016.704426] usb 1-1: reset high-speed USB device number 8 using xhci_hcd
[ 1049.430537] usb 1-1: reset high-speed USB device number 8 using xhci_hcd
[ 1060.550003] usb 1-1: USB disconnect, device number 8
[ 1060.550028] sd 1:0:0:0: Device offlined - not ready after error recovery
[ 1060.550043] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_ABORT driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[ 1060.550048] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 08 00
[ 1060.550052] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 0
[ 1060.550061] Buffer I/O error on dev sdb, logical block 0, async page read
[ 1060.550120] sd 1:0:0:0: rejecting I/O to offline device
[ 1060.550143] ldm_validate_partition_table(): Disk read failed.
[ 1060.550176] Dev sdb: unable to read RDB block 0
[ 1060.550226]  sdb: unable to read partition table
[ 1060.550597] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] Read Capacity(10) failed: Result: hostbyte=DID_NO_CONNECT driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[ 1060.550600] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] Sense not available.
[ 1060.550605] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] 0 512-byte logical blocks: (0 B/0 B)
[ 1060.550629] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI disk
[ 1911.705428] usb 1-1: new high-speed USB device number 9 using xhci_hcd
[ 1911.846722] usb 1-1: New USB device found, idVendor=152d, idProduct=2338
[ 1911.846727] usb 1-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=5
[ 1911.846730] usb 1-1: Product: USB to ATA/ATAPI bridge
[ 1911.846732] usb 1-1: Manufacturer: JMicron
[ 1911.846734] usb 1-1: SerialNumber: 000000000000
[ 1911.847857] usb-storage 1-1:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[ 1911.848150] scsi host1: usb-storage 1-1:1.0
[ 1912.878129] scsi 1:0:0:0: Direct-Access     ST310005 28AS                  PQ: 0 ANSI: 5
[ 1912.878875] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] 1953525168 512-byte logical blocks: (1.00 TB/932 GiB)
[ 1912.878927] sd 1:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg1 type 0
[ 1912.879139] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] Write Protect is off
[ 1912.879142] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] Mode Sense: 28 00 00 00
[ 1912.879425] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] No Caching mode page found
[ 1912.879431] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
[ 1944.367889] usb 1-1: reset high-speed USB device number 9 using xhci_hcd
[ 1977.122025] usb 1-1: reset high-speed USB device number 9 using xhci_hcd
[ 1988.265153] sd 1:0:0:0: Device offlined - not ready after error recovery
[ 1988.265173] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_ABORT driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[ 1988.265180] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 08 00
[ 1988.265184] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 0
[ 1988.265188] usb 1-1: USB disconnect, device number 9
[ 1988.265197] Buffer I/O error on dev sdb, logical block 0, async page read
[ 1988.265250] sd 1:0:0:0: rejecting I/O to offline device
[ 1988.265274] sd 1:0:0:0: rejecting I/O to offline device
[ 1988.265281] ldm_validate_partition_table(): Disk read failed.
[ 1988.265290] sd 1:0:0:0: rejecting I/O to offline device
[ 1988.265301] sd 1:0:0:0: rejecting I/O to offline device
[ 1988.265312] sd 1:0:0:0: rejecting I/O to offline device
[ 1988.265323] sd 1:0:0:0: rejecting I/O to offline device
[ 1988.265329] Dev sdb: unable to read RDB block 0
[ 1988.265338] sd 1:0:0:0: rejecting I/O to offline device
[ 1988.265349] sd 1:0:0:0: rejecting I/O to offline device
[ 1988.265387]  sdb: unable to read partition table
[ 1988.267016] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] Read Capacity(10) failed: Result: hostbyte=DID_NO_CONNECT driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[ 1988.267022] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] Sense not available.
[ 1988.267032] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] 0 512-byte logical blocks: (0 B/0 B)
[ 1988.267075] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI disk
[ 2167.158983] usb 1-1: new high-speed USB device number 10 using xhci_hcd
[ 2167.300232] usb 1-1: New USB device found, idVendor=152d, idProduct=2338
[ 2167.300237] usb 1-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=5
[ 2167.300240] usb 1-1: Product: USB to ATA/ATAPI bridge
[ 2167.300242] usb 1-1: Manufacturer: JMicron
[ 2167.300244] usb 1-1: SerialNumber: 000000000000
[ 2167.301229] usb-storage 1-1:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[ 2167.301516] scsi host1: usb-storage 1-1:1.0
[ 2168.319867] scsi 1:0:0:0: Direct-Access     ST310005 28AS                  PQ: 0 ANSI: 5
[ 2168.321028] sd 1:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg1 type 0
[ 2168.321243] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] 1953525168 512-byte logical blocks: (1.00 TB/932 GiB)
[ 2168.321571] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] Write Protect is off
[ 2168.321577] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] Mode Sense: 28 00 00 00
[ 2168.321863] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] No Caching mode page found
[ 2168.321875] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
[ 2200.381339] usb 1-1: reset high-speed USB device number 10 using xhci_hcd
[ 2233.107466] usb 1-1: reset high-speed USB device number 10 using xhci_hcd
[ 2244.250856] sd 1:0:0:0: Device offlined - not ready after error recovery
[ 2244.250860] usb 1-1: USB disconnect, device number 10
[ 2244.250875] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_ABORT driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[ 2244.250881] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 08 00
[ 2244.250884] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 0
[ 2244.250894] Buffer I/O error on dev sdb, logical block 0, async page read
[ 2244.250949] sd 1:0:0:0: rejecting I/O to offline device
[ 2244.250969] sd 1:0:0:0: rejecting I/O to offline device
[ 2244.250975] ldm_validate_partition_table(): Disk read failed.
[ 2244.251008] Dev sdb: unable to read RDB block 0
[ 2244.251059]  sdb: unable to read partition table
[ 2244.251470] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] Read Capacity(10) failed: Result: hostbyte=DID_NO_CONNECT driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[ 2244.251474] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] Sense not available.
[ 2244.251484] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] 0 512-byte logical blocks: (0 B/0 B)
[ 2244.251525] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI disk
```

below lsusb -v

```
Bus 001 Device 011: ID 152d:2338 JMicron Technology Corp. / JMicron USA Technology Corp. JM20337 Hi-Speed USB to SATA & PATA Combo Bridge
Couldn't open device, some information will be missing

Device Descriptor:
  bLength                18
  bDescriptorType         1
  bcdUSB               2.00
  bDeviceClass            0 (Defined at Interface level)
  bDeviceSubClass         0 
  bDeviceProtocol         0 
  bMaxPacketSize0        64
  idVendor           0x152d JMicron Technology Corp. / JMicron USA Technology Corp.
  idProduct          0x2338 JM20337 Hi-Speed USB to SATA & PATA Combo Bridge
  bcdDevice            1.00
  iManufacturer           1 
  iProduct                2 
  iSerial                 5 
  bNumConfigurations      1
  Configuration Descriptor:
    bLength                 9
    bDescriptorType         2
    wTotalLength           32
    bNumInterfaces          1
    bConfigurationValue     1
    iConfiguration          4 
    bmAttributes         0xc0
      Self Powered
    MaxPower                2mA
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        0
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           2
      bInterfaceClass         8 Mass Storage
      bInterfaceSubClass      6 SCSI
      bInterfaceProtocol     80 Bulk-Only
      iInterface              6 
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x81  EP 1 IN
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0200  1x 512 bytes
        bInterval               0
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x02  EP 2 OUT
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0200  1x 512 bytes
        bInterval               0
```

Comment: You opened it... you broke it. Whatever was wrong with it before is now unfixable. Hope you have a backup.

Comment: @Tetsujin I agree that opening the drive was a very bad move, however it does not mean that no data can be recovered from it. I'm pretty sure data recovery experts will be able to retrieve some data off the drive but possibly not affordably, and with a lower recovery rate. Waheedi - for next time, it's a good idea to ask first. There are techniques and mitigations which are more likely to work - including a controlled drop of the drive and cleanroom / dust reduction techniques and possibly others.

Comment: I actually disagree with both your comments (but thanks for commenting anyway), opening a hard drive should not have any real risks. unless you start to scratch your platters. as long as the platters are in good shape with no signs of any scratches, that means you can recover it whatsoever. Anyway. I thought some experts have had a similar issues, and obviously the question is not meant for newbies.

Comment: The tiniest speck of dust on any of the platters can cause a head-crash. At the speeds they spin it's the data-equivalent of a train crash. Your only hope now is a data recovery specialist. As already pointed out by @davidgo they are expensive & make no guarantees.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On your video I see the top of the drive is off. Ignoring my earlier comments about dust (which I still stand by - and indeed running the disk with the platters exposed will be even worse), the drive lid is a structural element of the drive and needs to be on with the correct torque on the screws - [this](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=5CAn22TiVV0) YouTube video demonstrates the importance of correct torque.

Comment: Thanks for sharing that information David. Surely I found that screws plays with the torque. After I replaced back screws I tightened them well. starting from the head screw. I now hear no noise or clicks. the hard drive seems to be spinning in the right fashion. Still I'm not able to mount it. working on it. Thanks again

Comment: Is there any sign of life in the drive ? If so, I'd strongly urge you to use ddrescue or similar to clone the available bits to another disk, then copy that and attempt to rescue data (eg using photorec)

Comment: Yes there is a sign of life, i hear the normal starting sound of a hard drive. Clicking still happens but its a normal click sound that happens every now and then. I will try the ddrescue. Thanks for the help again David. Will update results.

Comment: From the output it seems like you are using a USB to SATA bridge. In my experience this can throw spanners in the works. If at all possible could the drive directly to a SATA controller on the motherboard when doing recovery work. (I've got a spare PC for just this purpose after too many failures using USB)

Comment: indeed David. I think the USB/SATA thing is not the best way to deal with the current situation. I will connect it to a desktop directly and see how that will go.